# Scala Try[String] found instead of String

Tags: scala, file, io, functional-programming, try-catch

I am trying to understand how Try works in scala (not try/catch) but Try. As an example, here I wish to check if the file exists, and if yes, I will use the data in the file later in the code, but it doesn't work:

```
val texte = Try(Source.fromFile(chemin_texte).getLines().filter(_!="").foldLeft(""){_+_})
        texte match {
          case Success(x) => x
          case Failure(e) => println("An error occured with the text file"); println("Error: " + e.getMessage)
        }

        /*phrases du texte*/
        val phrases_txt = split_phrases(texte).map(phrase => phrase)
```

At `val phrases_txt` I wish to use the output of `texte` if the file exists, if not the program should halt at `Failure(e)`.

The error that I get is type mismatch; found: `scala.util.Try[String] required: String` .

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You need to assign the result of the match to a variable. `texte` is a `Try[String]`. When it's a success, the result of the match is the `String` you want to pass to `split_phrases`.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but if I do `val temp = texte match ...` then I can't call split_phrases(temp) because it says it returns Any instead of String - I agree with the fact that in case of Success it's a String, but we don't take into account the Failure

Comment: Oh true... You probably want to `map` the `Try`: `texte.map(x => split_phrases(x)...)` and then check for success at the end, rather than in the middle.

Comment: my best advice on such situations is to add explicit types to each var/val you have in the code. If you are using an IDE it's even easier. you will see some val it's not the type you are thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `Try` as just a container for a computation that can fail. It is not comparable with a try and catch block because they just "throw" the exceptions, which are expected to be handled later on in the program. Scala `Try` forces you to ensure that a possible error is handled at all times from that point onwards in your program.

You can do something like this:

```
val texte = Try(Source.fromFile(chemin_texte).getLines().filter(_!="").foldLeft(""){_+_})

val phrases: Try[List[String]] = texte.map(split_phrases)
```

I don't see the point of `.map(phrases => phrases)` because it will return the same object. The `map` function has a type of `T[A] => T[B]`, so that means that for a container with values of type `A`, the `map` will run a given function `f` on the *contents of the container* and produce a container of type `B` where function `f` is responsible for converting an object of type `A` to type `B`.

If you wish to further use your `phrases` object in your program with other values that produce `Try` values, you can use the `flatMap` function or `for` expressions that make life easier. For example:

```
val morePhrases: Try[List[String]] = ???

def mergePhrases(phrases1: List[String], phrases2: List[String]): Phrases = phrases1 ++ phrases2

val mergedPhrases: Try[List[String]] = for {
  p1 <- phrases
  p2 <- morePhrases
} yield mergePhrases(p1, p2) // Only for demonstration, you could also do yield p1 ++ p2
```

The `mergedPhrases` value in the code above is just a `Try` container containing the result of application of `mergePhrases` function on contents of `phrases` and `morePhrases`.

Note that the `Try` block may not *always* be the best way to capture error at the end of your program you'll what the first error occurred, but you won't know what exactly the error was. That's why we have things like `Either`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But what about xxx match { case Success() and Failure() } ?